# How do I prevent a font from extending off the top of a textbox?

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, fonts

I'm using a barcode font (IDAutomationMC39H) in an SSRS 2005 report I'm developing, and while it renders fine in the preview in BIDS, if I export the results to PDF, print the results, or do any of the above (including preview) in Report Manager, the barcode font is extending off the top of the textbox. The barcode itself is nearly 20px tall, even at only a 12pt size. I've tried changing the CanGrow value for the textbox, but it seems that even with that set off the barcode isn't pushing the bottom edge of the textbox downwards, it's simply extending over the top of the box. I've also tried resizing the textbox to allow it to contain the entire height of the font, but even with the VerticalAlign set to Bottom the barcode still sticks to the top of the textbox and overflows out the top. 
See screenshot here:
[http://imgur.com/JDC4Z.png](https://imgur.com/JDC4Z.png)

Does anyone know how to force the font to be bound by the top of the box, instead of overlapping it?

Comment: That link is asking for a sign-up/sign-in.  No thanks.  Please rehost the screenshot on something like imgur.com

Comment: @DiPaolo: Thanks, changed the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with no real success to get font-based barcoding to work. Ended up getting the boss to pay for [NeoDynamic BarCode Professional](http://www.neodynamic.com/Products/BCRS/BarcodeRS.aspx?tabid=78&prodid=7) which works *great* and has a lot more flexibility than fonts.